# Why text in the anchor tag is not visible?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The text in the anchor tag like `feature`, `pricing` are not at all visible. I tried adding color attribute but it doesn't seem to work. It just changes the cursor to click, but I can see only white background.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Feature ::::s</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's some CSS that's hiding it. Can you inspect the element in dev tools and check firstly that the element is there, and then what styles are being applied to it?

Comment: add `bg-dark` class in nav element because you used `navbar-dark` which changes foreground color to white

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but I notice you don't have the .nav class in this set of elements. I believe this may be necessary for Bootstrap 3, even though you're using the nav element.

Comment: I am new to this site and I wonder why my answer got downvoted? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `navbar` has been entirely rewritten in `bootstrap-4`, in which `.navbar-default` is now `.navbar-light`, while  `.navbar-dark` remains the same. **One of these classes is required on each `navbar`**. However, these classes no longer set background-colors; instead they essentially only affect color.
So you have 2 options:

1. Use any light background such as `.bg-light` when you use `.navbar-light`.
2. Use any dark background such as `.bg-dark` when you use `.navbar-dark`.

Because you used `.navbar-dark`, I think you want dark navigational bar. If you want to make your navigation bar stand-out from the page body, use `.bg-dark` on `nav` tag. In case you want to show trasparent navigation bar on your page body, use`.bg-dark` on `body` tag instead.

Comment: I am new to this site and I wonder why my answer got downvoted? :(

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote...  maybe because someone didn't read all the answer and thought your answer was about `.navbar-default` because thats what you talk about at the beginning? Your answer might be more helpful if it included an example to show how it would fix the problem in the question, but that's not a reason for a downvote. Have an upvote to balance it out :)

Comment: MattJHoughton already showed him code. So I haven't repasted it. I told him the reason for this change (which MattJHoughton forget to mention) and also showed him another option of making transparent nav-bar.
Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are not collaborative, each answer should be standalone and contain everything required. What if Matt changed or deleted that answer, or closed his account and it got removed?

Answer (score 4):

They're there - just white.

You need to set your background color on the nav - with [bg-dark.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark primary-color">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Feature ::::s</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`navbar-dark` is intended to be matched with dark background. So, all its childs are having foreground color of white. That's why the texts are there but can't be seen.

For using custom color as background, you need to use `!important` in the css for `primary-color`.

```css
.primary-color {
    background-color: #234567 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Feature ::::s</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```